# Python 3.8 Module not found error after having it installed in the command line

Tags: python, pip, folium

I am using python 3.8.3 version.
I installed folium typing `pip install folium` in the command line.  After typing `pip show folium` in the command line, the output is as follows:

```
Name: folium
Version: 0.12.1
Summary: Make beautiful maps with Leaflet.js & Python
Home-page: https://github.com/python-visualization/folium
Author: Rob Story
Author-email: wrobstory@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages
Requires: requests, jinja2, branca, numpy
Required-by:
```

When I type `import folium` in VS code, I get an `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folium'` error.
What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: No, I am using python 3.8 only

Comment: use `python -m pip install folium`, once you activate python interpreter in terminal using python command you will get it

Comment: tried it, didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your package seems to be installed in `c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages`.

Check out where is your Python looking for installed packages by running this Python program:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

If there is not aforementioned path present, then you have to add it, for VS code it is described here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Answer (score 3):

Avoiding this kind of errors, always use virtualenv.

Take a look here

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting VSCode, sometimes the python extension needs a restart so newly installed modules are indexed.

You can try running the code despite the Error in VSCode. It works if you can confirm that the required module is properly installed.

Answer (score -1):

Can you  open python in command line and type

```
>>> import folium
```

In my case I got error as I don't have it installed. If you get error on command line, it means module was not installed.
[CMD screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuLUy.png)

Comment: as I wrote, I tried it and it worked, but when I import the module in the editor, I get an error.

Comment: No where you mention that you used import folium in python interpreter on command line, please be specific.